# Use PGXN to install pg_repack on postgres 9.6 on top of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

So I have Ubuntu 14.04 with postgres 9.6 and I wanted to install pg_repack so I did

```
sudo apt-get install pgxnclient`
sudo pgxn install pg_repack
```

but I got an error (sorry I forgot the error) and I found a site saying I need

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-all
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
```

I suspect that one or both of those came in as Postgresql 10 because when I did

```
sudo pgxn install pg_repack
```

it seems to work except for that it is putting the files in `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin` when I'm still running 9.6 server.

Can I just move that to `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin` or is there something specific about it to postgres10 that won't work if I just move it?

Secondly, how do I configure `pgxn` to use 9.6 and not 10?

The website [here](http://pgxnclient.projects.pgfoundry.org/) is dead so I imagine there's documentation out there that I can't get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgxn` will install using the `PostgreSQL` associated with whatever `pg_config` it finds first in `$PATH`.  If you set your PATH (either permanently or temporarily) to list first the directory containing that pg_config then that should fix the problem

```
sudo su
PATH=/some/version/postgres/bin:$PATH
pgxn install pg_repack
```

Comment: OK this didn't solve my problem directly but it got me going in the right direction.  I didn't have any `postgres/bin` in my path but my `/usr/bin` (which is in the path) had the ver 10 of pg_config so I copied the ver 9.6 to my usr/bin and then ran the install command again which solved the problem.