# How to install pg_repack in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

1. [Use PGXN to install pg_repack on postgres 9.6 on top of Ubuntu 14.04](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203087/use-pgxn-to-install-pg-repack-on-postgres-9-6-on-top-of-ubuntu-14-04)
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/617751/default-location-of-postgresql-when-installing-through-apt-get
3. https://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/#installation

I also want to install pg_repack.
I finished the following two command.
`sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-all`
`sudo apt-get install postgresql-common`

`sudo apt-get install pgxnclient` successful.

`sudo su`
`PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin:$PATH`  successful.
`pgxn install pg_repack` then error occurred.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llz4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lreadline
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:475: pg_repack] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/tmpxh8zkbcg/pg_repack-1.4.7/bin'
make: *** [Makefile:35: all] Error 2
ERROR: command returned 2: make PG_CONFIG=/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_config all
```

Answer (score 1):

I think compiler not found 2 libraries:

- /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llz4
- /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lreadline

you need to install them. I had similar problem with my alpine docker container. I fixed this by installing missing libraries lz4-dev, gawk:

```
#apk add lz4-dev

#apk add gawk
```

after that extension pg_repack was built successfully.
As example https://github.com/Raul-dev/Migration-MSSQL-toPostgres/blob/main/source/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Usually `pg_repack` is installed from the repository rather than from sources.

Check your OS repositories, typically the package is named:

- `postgresql-15-repack` - Debian family/Ubuntu
- `pg_repack15` - Red Hat family/CentoS/Rocky

Where `15` is the major version of the postgresql for which the extension is built.